# Usar correctamente gridstack en Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Actualmente trabajo con la versión de Angular 8.2.2. Estoy tratando de usar la librería de Angular de GridStack tal y como viene en el [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w4khgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgridstack%2Fgridstack.component.ts) pero no logro que me funcione como en la demo.

Utilizo la misma versión de GridStack que en el ejemplo pero nunca llega a tener la misma funcionalidad. El HTML se genera correctamente, con las clases que debe tener:

```
<div _ngcontent-dql-c13="" class="grid-stack grid-stack-instance-635 grid-stack-animate grid-stack-6" gs-current-row="4" style="height: 280px;">
    <div class="grid-stack-item grid-stack-item" gs-x="0" gs-y="0" gs-w="2" gs-h="2">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-stack-item grid-stack-item" gs-x="1" gs-y="3" gs-w="1" gs-h="1">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-stack-item grid-stack-item" gs-x="2" gs-y="3" gs-w="3" gs-h="1">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content">item2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se puede ver que es lo mismo. Pero se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, no tiene  ningún cuadrado del color que debería a pesar de que el css está correctamente importado en el módulo. Siendo este, por supuesto, el mismo que el del stackblitz de ejemplo. El cual se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación pongo lo que tengo en mi componente:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GridStack } from 'gridstack';

@Component({
  selector: 'site-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './site-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class SiteDashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public id: number;
  public gridStack: GridStack;
  data = 234;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.siteId;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options = {
      column: 6,
      minRow: 1,
      cellHeight: 70,
      disableOneColumnMode: true,
      float: false,
      removable: '.trash',
      acceptWidgets: function (el) {
        return true;
      },
    };

    GridStack.setupDragIn('.sidebar .grid-stack-item', {
      revert: 'invalid',
      scroll: false,
      appendTo: 'body',
      helper: this.handleDrop.bind(this),
    });

    this.gridStack = GridStack.init(options).float(true);

    const serializedData = [
      { x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2 },
      { x: 2, y: 3, w: 3, content: 'item2' },
      { x: 1, y: 3 }
    ];

    this.gridStack.load(serializedData);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleDrop(event: any): void {
    return event.target.cloneNode(true);
  }

}
```

```
<div class="grid-stack">
    
</div>
```

Comment: El div del stackblitz se ve de diferente color porque en el styles.scss (el estilo principal) hay una clase que le pone ese estilo, no porque se lo ponga gridstack... `.grid-stack-item-content {color: #2c3e50;text-align: center;background-color: #18bc9c;`

Comment: Ya, por eso digo que el estilo del css es el mismo, no vi relevante ponerlo. Además preguntaba por el tema de la funcionalidad.